# Tutorials and examples for mgwt/gwt-phonegap

Tags: gwt, cordova, mgwt

I have been trying to follow mgwt and gwt-phonegap through code.google.com. It feels like a pain for me, because I can't find something properly described there for a beginner to follow.
Can any one plz suggest me a good tutorial site or examples for mgwt/gwtphonegap?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you have questions on how to get started the mgwt user group ( https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mgwt ) is a very good place to ask questions and there have been already a tremendous amount of questions about it on the group. 
We are very friendly (especially to inexperienced users)

Check out the wiki:

- http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/GettingStarted
- http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/SetupProject

Check out the blog:
 - http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/06/using-mgwt-and-gwt-phonegap.html

Also there are a couple of videos out there:

- General thoughts: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0V0CdhMFiao&feature=plcp
- Getting started: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSTuS52E0ko
- Simple App example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37dw1MY-GdU&list=PLE6023D47484AE16E&feature=view_all

We did not document the basics of GWT MVP. This is done very nicely in the GWT docs.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I really like the approach of mgwt and appreciate your time and effort. For a public API I still would ask for better JavaDoc in some places. Just a "Constructor for xx.", "handlerRegistration a {@link com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration} object" - so stuff that just documents the obvious is not so helpful. No offense, I hope you understand my request for developers going to use that nice API. Thx! :)

Comment: Hi Daniel, Could you please update the tutorial to the new version? It is hard to find a working tutorial of the latest gwtphonegap. Thanks!